# Datetime data type in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have to migrate tables from oracle to redshift, I have to create a script, I need  to know that Can we use Datetime as a datatype instead of using Timestamp or date in oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `datetime` is not a recognised data type in Oracle.

The valid data types are listed in the documentation, which has a section on [datetime and interval data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7690645A-0EE3-46CA-90DE-C96DF5A01F8F):

> The datetime data types are `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, and `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. Values of datetime data types are sometimes called **datetimes**.

Some [ANSI and other data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF) are supported for compatibility, but there is no `datetime` type.

This is easy to check of course:

```
create table t42 (x datetime);

ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

But if you're writing a script to migrate from Oracle to somewhere else, you presumably don't want to be modifying the source Oracle schema anyway; you need your script to translate DDl and DML from Oracle syntax to the target DB syntax. Or you may find tools already exist (Amazon seems to have [its own tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html), for instance, if your source DB is suitable), or guidance from others who have done something similar in the past on blogs, etc.